# Group data by column data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've got some data in a pandas DataFrame:

```
     text                                               polarity
0    -Mi hijo es tan rico que le regalo un BMW a su...   NEUTRAL
1    The new BMW 3 Series is awarded 5 stars in the...   POSITIVE
2    @GEAGarratt BMW hand over 200 + electric vehic...   POSITIVE
3    I asked Sauber about more info or images of th...   NEUTRAL
4    bmw >>>     NEUTRAL
```

What I would like is to group these by column, for later plotting the number of instances of each polarity. I've been trying with different groupby combinations, but have so far failed. I would love a small push.

That is, I'm probably looking for output similar to this

```
'polarity' 'text'
NEUTRAL    -Mi hijo es tan rico que le regalo un BMW a su...
           I asked Sauber about more info or images of th...
POSITIVE   The new BMW 3 Series is awarded 5 stars in the...
           The new BMW 3 Series is awarded 5 stars in the...
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Say your dataframe was called my_dataframe, the syntax would be something like:

```
my_dataframe[my_dataframe['polarity'] == 'POSTIVE']['text']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to plot the number of instances, say in a bar chart or something, I would suggest the following:

```
df.groupby('polarity').count().plot(kind='bar')
```

This will give you a bar chart of the groupby object with the counts for polarity. If you just want the dataframe to be returned grouped, then just use the first part of what I did above.

```
grouped = df.groupby('polarity')
```

This should leave you with your desired output.

I would recommend reading up on the [pandas groupby method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/groupby.html#group-by-split-apply-combine) which will give you a better understanding of working with data in the way you hope to.

Answer (score 0):

To output something like what you expect, you can:

First, use `reindex` to set the order of columns

Then use `sort` to sort the dataframe by the polarity

```
df.reindex(columns=['polarity', 'text']).sort('polarity')
```